# How to show Messagebox after few clicks in C#

Tags: c#, messagebox

I want to show a messagebox after my button is pressed 10 times.
If the user has clicked on the button 10 times then it should appear a messagebox

I've tried:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++ )
{
    MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());
}
```

It brings me nothing

Comment: Is this the code that gets called when the button is clicked?

Comment: Where is your logic for the 10 button presses? What method is this in?

Comment: Are you trying to make a message box appear or make text appear in a prexisting message box?

Comment: Sorry for my wrong code. If the user has pressed on my button after 10 times, then a messagebox should appear.

Comment: clicked* not pressed sorry

Comment: add a counter to the buttons click event. if the counter == 10 call show on a message box?

Comment: code you gave us shows message box 5 times, how it is related to your question?

Answer (score 2):

> If the user has clicked on the button 10 times then it should appear a messagebox

It's not clear why you're trying to use a *loop* for this.  There's nothing over which to iterate in the description.  You're simply incrementing a counter with each click and performing an action when the counter equals a given value.

First you need to track the number of clicks.  A class-level property should do the trick:

```
private int NumberOfClicks { get; set; }
```

Then in your click handler, you increment it:

```
NumberOfClicks++;
```

Each time it's incremented, check if it's at 10 yet and show the message:

```
if (NumberOfClicks == 10)
    MessageBox.Show("some message");
```

(You could additionally reset the counter in the `if` block, so that the message is shown *every* 10 clicks.  Or check if `NumberOfClicks % 10 == 0` for the same effect.  Etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Add a variable holding the current clickcount to your forms class. Every time you click the button, increase it. If the counter reaches 10 show the messagebox and reset the counter.

```
public partial class MyForm : Form {
    private int clickcount = 0;

    public MyForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        button1.Click += clicked;
    }

    public void clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (++clickcount == 10) {
            MessageBox.Show("hello there!");
           clickcount = 0;
        }           

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a working form button named buttonOne and a Messagebox  called messagebox

```
private int clickcount { get; set; } 
private void buttonOne_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    if(++clickcount == 10)
       MessageBox.Show("Your message")
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this

Comment: Having a private auto property is absolutely useless, if not less beneficial as you can't pass it to a ref or out.